# ¿Como pasar datos de un controlador a un modulo incluido con @include Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel-5, aplicación-web, laravel-blade

estoy desarrollando una web con Laravel y necesito pasar los datos que vienen de un controlador a un modulo llamado `seciones.blade.php` que esta en una carpeta llamada `includes`, de modo que la extructura queda así:

```
includes/secciones.blade.php
index.blade.php
```

En el archivo `index.blade.php` tengo incluido el archivo en cuestión con Laravel Blade de la siguiente forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Innova Soluciones | Home </title>
</head>
<body>
    @include('includes/secciones')
</body>
```

Tengo la siguiente ruta que me lleva a un Controlador llamado `PrincipalController@index`:

```
Route::get('/', 'PrincipalController@index');
```

`PrincipalController@index` ejecuta el metodo `index` que lo que hace es retornar la vista donde esta incluido el modulo `includes/secciones.blade.php` de la siguiente forma:

```
class PrincipalController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('index');
    }
}
```

Dentro del archivo `includes/secciones.blade.php` tengo un menú estatico que quiero sustituirlo con los datos que estan la base de datos:

```
<section class="seccion_categorias_items">
    <div class="item">
        <label class="item_img"><img src="img/logos/svg/zapatos.svg"></label>
        <h1 class="item_titulo">Innovate Zapatos </h1>
        <a class="item_link" href="/"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- ... las demas opciones aquí --> 
</section>
```

El proceso de pasar los datos del controlador hacia este modulo que este fuera o en otra ubicación de donde esta la vista `index.blade.php` es el que desconosco, ya que el metodo `index` de `PrincipalController` solo devolvería la vista `index.blade.php` con los datos de ESA vista y no del modulo `secciones.blade.php`.

Espero haberme explicado, si no es así les pido que amablemente pregunten, agradezco sus aportes o sugerencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada tienes que devolver esa data en tu controlador

```
class PrincipalController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $data = ['opciones'=>$opciones];
        return view('index')->with($data);;
    }
}
```

Luego deberás pasar esa data como parámetro en tu `@include`

```
@include('includes.secciones', ['data.opciones' => 'opciones'])
```

Y en tu archivo `includes/secciones.blade.php` debes usar esos datos

```
<h4>Mis opciones</h4>
@foreach ($opciones as $opcion)
    <p>{{ $opcion }}</p>
@endforeach
```

---

Todo lo explicado se encuentra en la documentación oficial de Laravel acerca de [Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade)

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado.

Comment: De nada, suerte en tu proyecto!